# Custom email verification laravel fortify

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, fortify

I apologize in advance if you don't understand at any point.

context** I am building a web application in Laravel, although I am very new, I am doing well. I implemented the laravel fotify package for user authentication and others, all perfect. Now, in the same way, I use Laravel Socialite to allow login and registration with Google.

now, according to laravel fortify I can implement email verification, which I did according to the documentation and it works perfect. My question or use case that I would like to solve is:

that users who logged in with google are not asked for this verification, since I consider it a bit redundant, however I still have not found the solution.
In my users table, I have a type_auth field where I store the type of authentication that was done. example: google

My idea is to cancel the verification using this field.

I would appreciate any ideas or if this is impossible.

thank you.

Comment: I'd just set `email_verified_at` to the current date when you create the Google authed users.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but it doesn't seem to work, I included said field when creating it but it is not reflected in the database and even so it asks for verification.

Comment: ok, you were right, you just need to add the email_verified_at to the protected $fillable array of the users model